# how to find modified branch of a repo using Github Push event

Tags: php, git, api, github, github-api

I am using GitHub repo web hook to get to my site pinged when new changes occurs. i dont know who to find which branch is modified.

I referred github docs and in that

The full Git ref that was pushed. Example: "refs/heads/master".

i dont know if that is a correct way to find the modified branch

if yes then will the path will be the same for all repo ?

i get the below json http://pastebin.com/GaFQME7d

Comment: Would you accept an answer that would work for command line git (I don't know much about github)? i.e. can you make the hook ping back the output of an arbitrary git command?

Comment: notsure.. i just want to know which is the correct way of getting the branch. if that works for me sure i will accept it

Comment: My idea was to sort the branch names by commit date, that will get you the most recently changed branch, which should be the branch that was just pushed. Let me know if you'd like to see that as an answer

Comment: @mwm314 no not like that .. i have just add the json i get i just wanted to find which branch is pushed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out you have all the required information is the GitHub push event. (webhook)

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent

You already know that the `ref` is the name of the branch.
And this is the right way to do it, this is what this hook is for.

> if yes then will the path will be the same for all repo ?

Yep, you only have 1 main repo with many forks, all the commits should be pushed to your central repo.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the ref give the values like `ref/head/{branch-name}`  i just wanted to know is the `ref/head/` is the standard path and also ill get all of the api calls ?

Comment: Yep, is named refspec and this is the way git track your branches. read about it in here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec